# Control your smartphone using your laptop please answer!

Tags: hardware

I have a sony xperia zr and the lower screen recently smashed. Touch screen capability has also gone. Does anyone know of an app or a method for connecting it to my laptop and gaining full control of the phone through the laptop?

PS: I reformat my phone!

Answer (score 0):

Sony ZR supports OTG, so im sure this will work. What you have to do is Buy an OTG cable and connect USB Mouse via USB cable and try using the mouse pointer. Also Keyboard should work.

But if your screen doesnt show at all, then im sorry.